# how to read a script (which is stored as a file) in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want gnuplot to read a script and produce graphs accordingly.
what kind of file should the script be and what is the syntax of reading the file.

Comment: Write all gnuplot commands into a text file, and either run `gnuplot` from the command line giving this file as argument, or use `load` in interactive mode to read in the script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To run a script called '*filename*', you can type

```
gnuplot "filename"
```

or from within an interactive gnuplot environment you can load a script file by typing

```
load "filename"
```

Edit: As per Gabriel's comment below, you can let the plot generated by a script persist and close your gnuplot session by using the *-p* or *--persist* option. Do note that the plot which persists won't have any interactive features like zooming/scrolling.

```
gnuplot -p "filename"
```

More info available on the [gnuplot official documentation](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.0/gnuplot.pdf)(page 22)

Comment: You might want to also pass the option `-p` or else the window plot could close immediately, giving the impression that nothing happens for short and fast scripts. [source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257679/how-to-keep-gnuplot-x11-graph-window-open-until-manually-closed)

Comment: How do you run a gnuplot script like this but also have an interactive persistent graph?